# Browserstack automation through VPN

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

Has any one used browser stack for automation while connecting to a web application which needs VPN connection.

I have tried the code provided by browser stack - https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/getting-started/java/local-testing#understand-your-local-test-script

Also, tried setting proxy - https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/test-behind-proxy/configure-settings

However, when the application url is opened in the browser, its displays the message "The request is blocked" on the browser. This happens when you try to access the web application without VPN connection.

code is as below:

```
if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("browserStack")){

                //Creates an instance of Local
                Local bsLocal = new Local();

                DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
                caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");
                caps.setCapability("os_version", "10");
                caps.setCapability("browser", "Firefox");
                caps.setCapability("browser_version", "latest");
                caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");
                caps.setCapability("browserstack.selenium_version", "4.1.0");

                                                
                HashMap<String, String> bsLocalArgs = new HashMap<String, String>();

                bsLocalArgs.put("key", AUTOMATE_ACCESS_KEY);
                bsLocalArgs.put("force", "true");
                bsLocalArgs.put("forcelocal", "true");
                bsLocalArgs.put("forceproxy", "true");
                bsLocalArgs.put("proxyHost", "fpx-primary.mycompany.com");
                bsLocalArgs.put("proxyPort", "8080");


                // Starts the Local instance with the required arguments
                
               try {
                    bsLocal.start(bsLocalArgs);

                    // Check if BrowserStack local instance is running

                    System.out.println("bsLocal.isRunning():" + bsLocal.isRunning());
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);

            } 
            
            
            driver.get("https://application.url");
            
            bsLocal.stop();
        }
```